# A reference for "Borel Sets and Circuit Complexity"

Tags: reference-request, computational-complexity, computability-theory

Is there any pdf version of M.Sipser's "Borel Sets and Circuit Complexity" or , since I am unable to get this paper, is there other reference closely related to theory in that paper?

Comment: the pdf is [here](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=808733)

Comment: The license authorizing redistribution without commercial advantage, you may legally find it [here](http://booksc.org/book/23380681).

Comment: @Michaël --- hmm, if I click on "request permission" and check "post on the internet, non-profit", the publisher asks for a $500 payment ....

Comment: @CarloBeenakker: I'm certainly not posting it myself, though :-)  In any case, the PDF document itself clearly states that nonprofit copying is authorized, provided all the notices are kept.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you two kind help! May I ask that if I can get reference for the paper M.Sipser 'A topological view of some problems in complexity theory'?

Comment: http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0030341#page-1